# How does the NATO code name system work, are they just random names, or is there some sort of rule(s)?

Tags: aircraft-naming, nato

When an aircraft is designated a NATO code name, are there a certain rule(s) that contribute to the naming of an aircraft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_reporting_name#cite_note-NATO_list-1)

> They provide unambiguous and easily understood English words in a
>   uniform manner in place of the original designations, which either may
>   have been unknown to the Western world at the time or easily confused
>   codes.

Much the like the NATO alphabet rules the names but be easy to understand (possibly under multiple speaking accents) and must be non ambiguous.

The following rules are also applied

> **Aircraft**
>
> The first letter indicates the type of aircraft, like
>   Bear for a bomber aircraft, or Fulcrum for a fighter aircraft.
>
> **F** —
>   fighter aircraft, also later ground attack aircraft: [List of NATO
>   reporting names for fighter aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NATO_reporting_names_for_fighter_aircraft)
>
> **B** — bomber aircraft: [List of NATO
>   reporting names for bomber aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NATO_reporting_names_for_bomber_aircraft)
>
> **C** — commercial aircraft and
>   airliners, and cargo aircraft: [List of NATO reporting names for
>   transport aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NATO_reporting_names_for_transport_aircraft)
>
> **H** — helicopters: [List of NATO reporting names for
>   helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NATO_reporting_names_for_helicopters)
>
> **M** — Miscellaneous; trainers, reconnaissance, seaplanes,
>   tankers, AEW etc.: [List of NATO reporting names for miscellaneous
>   aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NATO_reporting_names_for_miscellaneous_aircraft)
>
> For fixed-wing aircraft, one syllable names were used for
>   propeller-powered craft (turboprops included), while two-syllable
>   names indicated jet engines.